# force:refreshView and Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, lightning

I am hitting this [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001C8QQAU&title=data-not-updated-in-ui-after-an-apex-update-in-lightning-experience) where edits in a Visualforce page once returned to the record are not reflecting in the UI in Lightning Experience. I can't refactor this into a Lightning Component because it uses a Visualforce component from Advanced Approvals. The workaround is `If you can’t refactor your component to use Lightning Data Service, you can also use force:refreshView to request a page refresh.`

My question is what would be an approach to continue to use the Visualforce page, but make it refresh the view once it returns back to the record page? I tried using `sforce.one.navigateToSObject`, but that still seems to have the same problem of the cache not being refreshed.

Comment: I'm interested to see someone answer this, as I was facing the same issue!